# Can Safari show the tab/window URL instead of its title?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

I am a web developer, I created a script that holds the entire process from A to Z, for deploying a local website with ease, setting you from repository cloning to logging in passing via database and file download using open software.

Since then, often I have many websites opened all synced with production, staging and local.

Is it possible (for Safari) to show URLs instead of page titles as the window/tab title?

Comment: Perhaps use a userscript that sets `document.title = document.location;` on page load.

Comment: No, there are many, many websites open... besides, I don't want to touch production.